# Outlook contact info as a vcard or .msg file

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, email-signature, vcard

I'm creating a contact info file which is uploaded to our website and linked to in coworkers signatures.

The most common file is a vcard but I've had issues where it only allows 4 specific phone number categories. We want a main with extension and direct dial number listed.

I realized I can create .msg files which seems to open the same way in outlook contacts with more customization.

Is there a particular benefit to using the vcard files vs the .msg files? Will I encounter any problems I'm not seeing yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSG files is a native Outlook format. It contains all the data associated with Outlook items including custom properties. vCard is an interop format recognizable by many systems including mobile devices, but it lacks some properties. If you're planning to access contact data using Outlook only, consider MSG format.

Comment: Thank you, is there another format that is even newer than vcard?

Comment: vCard itself has versions. The latest is 4.0.